# Jquery Contents() with load progress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

im loading content from another external page within the same website using contents() like the following where urlrequested is the page to loads url.. I cant seem to figure out how to display a progress bar that shows what level of completion grabbing the contents from the page is at. Its part of an ajax call and currently there is a few seconds between my preloader disappearing and the content loading. any help appreciated

```
namespace.ajax.done(function(urlrequested) {
    var linkrel = $(urlrequested).find("#containment").contents();
    $("#containment").html(linkrel);
    console.log('finished');
}),
```

Comment: https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/create-real-time-progress-bar-using-jquery-ui-ajax/ might help you.

Comment: No its not really what Im after, thanks thought

Comment: When you say progress bar, do you mean showing meter or percentage completed?  If so, I don't think you can.  If just a please wait kind of message, it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

With your AJAX request, you can set up an event handler for the progess event and check the percentage of completion like this:

```
//Download progress
XMLHttpRequest.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
  if (evt.lengthComputable) {  
    var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
    //Do something with download progress
  }
}, false);
```